# How do get the following PHP echo to output this JavaScript alert with a PHP variable?

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, php-5.6

I am using PHP 5.6 to use a database.

```
$connect = new mysqli($serverName, $username, $password);

if ($connect->connect_error){
$connectError = mysqli_connect_error();
    echo('<script> alert("Connection Failed :/'.$connectError.'")</script>');
}else{
    echo(('<script> alert("Connection success :)")</script>'));
}
```

the issue is that    $connectError stops the code outputing the javaScript alert how can i inclued the error message and output the alert?

Comment: Have you looked at your console.log to see if there's an errors there?

Comment: Using `alert()` is super heavy-handed. Why not show something in your HTML? Also check the source of the page that's rendered, and as aynber says, look for JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your `$connectError`:

```
$connect = new mysqli($serverName, $username, $password);

if ($connect->connect_error){
    $connectError = addslashes(mysqli_connect_error());
    echo('<script> alert("Connection Failed :/'.$connectError.'")</script>');
}else{
    echo(('<script> alert("Connection success :)")</script>'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in escaping quote marks. In my PHP code this works perfectly:

```
$message = "Connection Failed :/" .$connectError;
echo "<script>";
echo "alert(\"" .$message. "\");";  
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: When echoing any output to the web browser you should escape your output to prevent breaking HTML or JavaScript.